# Kyokushin in India?

Tags: karate

I have been looking for some trusted Masters of Kyokushin in India, but so far I have found only a few dojos in India with different versions of Kyokushin. Recently I learned about the splitting of Kyokushin organization into 3 parts led by Kancho Shokei Matsui ( IKO 1 ), Kancho Kenji Midori ( IKO 2).
Are there any trusted organizations of IKO 1 or IKO 2 in India ?

Comment: I found these two pages on Facebook. I am not able to figure out genuine one.
[Kyokushin Ifk India](https://www.facebook.com/kyokushinifk.india.9)
[Kyokushin Kai Kan India](https://www.facebook.com/kyokushinindia)

Comment: I don't understand how it appears to be off-topic If I am trying to ask the Martial arts community If they know any trusted sources of Kyokushin Karate in India.
My action of asking a question here was after researching online and inquiring with some sources.

Comment: It reads like a "where can I find X martial art in my area" type question, but I can see how you might edit it to be more helpful to the community.  If you asked specifically about the three organizations you mention, and alter the wording so that it's asking for facts instead of opinions, I can see this as a viable question.

Comment: To me it read like "I have looked at various places in my country and cannot find a trusted source, so is there any community member who is aware of IKO 1 or IKO 2 in India ?". Note the India is not 'my area'. For your knowledge it's 7th largest country in the World. And to not have a single trusted source of International Kyokushin Karate in India is sad.
If that is the reason to down-vote my question then I humbly request to read my question carefully one more time.

Comment: Okay, I did re-read your question.  I did not understand it at first. I recommend contacting the institution itself and directly asking.  This looks like a good place to start: http://www.kyokushinindia.com/

Comment: I have already contacted [kyokushinindia.com](http://www.kyokushinindia.com/) and waiting for a reply. The location of this dojo is in another province thousand miles away from my hometown and I am looking forward to relocate to that place. I have requested details of association with IKO 1, my decision to relocate is dependent on it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localised and shows no prior research whatsoever.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is based on one specific area.

Answer (score -1):

Most kyokushin dojos are located in Bengal, especially Kolkata. I know of some in South India as well, but if you live in West Bengal you can contact IFK or WKF. Shihan Sivaji Ganguly and Shihan Prasenjit Saha have trained directly under Mas Oyama, while the IFK India (KKAI) head, Shihan Santanu Ganguly, has trained under Hanshi Steve Arneil. I practise Kyokushin under IFK in Southern Kolkata, hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Shihan Shivaji  Ganguly was the direct disciple and branch chief of Sosai Mas Oyama . He was the only Indian to recieve 5th dan from Sosai . He was the only Indian to attend Uchideshi Camp Of Sosai Mas Oyama in its true sense .

Mr Santanu Ganguly was the student of Shihan Ganguly only

Comment: *Welcome to the site*. I strongly urge you to look at the [help] section to learn how we work. This answer makes lots of claims without any justifications. Could you add some?